# Most efficient way to check if object is a String

Tags: c++, string, performance, types, ros

I get an object (`msg.data`) that is either a number or a string. If it is a string I don't want to use it, if it is a number I want to. I currently solved this problem with an `ostringstream`, though I think there are way better solutions:

```
void scan_cb(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan)
{
float dist = 0.0f;

std::ostringstream s;
s << scan->ranges[0]; // can be string (always "inf") or a float
if(s.str() != "inf"){
    dist += scan->ranges[0];
}
...
```

I care about efficiency, because this is part of a for loop running many times each second.

The basic structure is a [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/msg) message, coming from a certain topic, and can have basically any data type.
In this case I use a [LaserScan message](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html), the documentation does not mention that `range[x]` can return *"inf"*.

Comment: You objects is *always* a string. What you want to do is parse the string.

Comment: I tried to clarify, my object is `msg.data` and it is not clear what type this is.

Comment: How is *declared* `msg.data`?

Comment: There's no variant data type in C++. If a union or similar way was used to store multiple data type in the class then you still have to check the data type and use the correct member

Comment: Yo'd probably also want to ignore `NaN` (Not a Number).

Comment: Could you show the line in **your** source where `msg` is declared?

Comment: Updated my example code, in the beginning I thought there would be a fast general solution for this problem.

Comment: I am voting to close, because the underlying problem is a huge misconception so that the question is unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to ROS documentation, `scan->ranges` is an array of float. That makes sense, because you add it to a float (`dist`) when the *string representation* of `ranges[0]` is not `inf`.

That means that (as MSalters guessed in its comment), you have a true float value, and you just want to make sure it is a real number and neither an infinite value nor a NaN (Not a Number) value.

So provided you include `cmath` (or `math.h`) you can use the C classifications macros to determine whether the number is finite (but subnormal values are allowed) or normal (even subnormal values are rejected):

```
void scan_cb(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan)
{
float dist = 0.0f;

if(isfinite(scan->ranges[0])){
    dist += scan->ranges[0];
}
...
```

(more references on IEEE-754 representation of floating point numbers on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point))